# I want to link two php pages at same time while i am using third page

Tags: php, mysql

i am using index.php page containting this codes

```
<form action="post.php" method="POST">
<textarea placeholder="write something.........." name="desc" "></textarea>
<input type='submit'  name='post' value='POST' />
<form>
```

and then when i click the submit button in the `index.php` will link me to `pos.php`

```
if(isset($_POST['post'])){
$description=$_POST['desc']; 
$sql = "INSERT INTO post(description) VALUES('$description')";
if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    //i need to get another third php file which automaticaly load when you click the submit butto in the idex.php
<a href="third.php">third Page</a>
  }
  else{
    echo 'failure'.mysqli_error($con);
  }
```

when i try this it makes me link than is third php but i donot want that 
i want to insert data into sql at same time linked me to the third page with out clicking any another link

can anyone help me

thanks!

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Please learn to use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Adulkadir.  Do you know about PHP Sessions?   I am not understanding your question about 'link two php pages at the same time'.  Are you able to click the Edit link under your question and give us more information about what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Would include do what you want?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

```
include('third.php');
```

This would add all code that is in third.php to your post.php and also load it's contents.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, you need to do a redirect after saving the data to the database.

html form:

```
<form action="do_something.php" method="post">
  <textarea placeholder="write something.........." name="desc" "></textarea>
  <input type='submit'  name='post' value='POST' />
<form>
```

do_something.php:

```
<?php
/*
* Do your sql; 
* use prepared statements; see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
* you'll have to look this up to implement it
*
*  $sql = "INSERT INTO post(description) VALUES(?)";
*
* bind value and execute.  
*/


/* 
* Note; there must be NO output before the header call!
*/

$newUrl = "http://yourDomain/third.php";
header('Location: '.$newURL);
die;
```

third.php

```
// page 3 loads immediately after do_something.php executes.
```

When you follow this pattern, the back button will not resubmit your POST data.